# how can i divide a list as subsets which are sum upto given number(non repeat)?

Tags: list, subset-sum

from given list of numbers

> nums=[4,3,2,3,5,2,1]

```
from itertools import combinations
nums=[4,3,2,3,5,2,1]
li=[]
for i in range(1,len(nums)):
    comb=combinations(nums,i)
    for j in comb:
        if sum(j)==5:
            li.append(j)

print(li)
```

and output is

```
[(5,), (4, 1), (3, 2), (3, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (2, 2, 1)]
```

I am able to find the subsets but the elements seem to be repeated
so interested in non-repeating elements

I want the list of subsets that gives sum equal to 5
**(without repetition)**

> example: [(5), (1, 4), (2,3), (2,3)]

Comment: There's a _repeatition_ in your _example_.

Comment: that's not repeatition as there frequency in list is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the loop slightly so that used numbers are removed from the list, they aren't reused in another sum, e. g.

```
i = 1
while i <= len(nums):
    comb = combinations(nums, i)
    for j in comb:
        if sum(j) == 5:
            li.append(j)
            for n in j: nums.remove(n)
            break
    else: i += 1    # increment only if nothing found
```